# How to Embedded the latest video from my youtube channel in my website

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, youtube-api

I'm trying to find a script to embed the latest video from my schools youtube channel into the school website home page.

I'm coding in asp, javascript and html

Cheers

John

Answer (score 4):

Just go to this url http://www.yvoschaap.com/youtube.html and you would find it useful for your need

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_USERNAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```